# acessing JSON in JavaScript to get the value of a particular key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, reactjs

- I am trying to get the key and `_html` value in JS
- Can you tell me how to access it?
- Right now I am getting only the below value

sportsTitle----->

```
[{
    "type": "p",
    "key": "100",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
        "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" : {
            "__html": "hello world"
        }
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
}]
```

**providing my code below**

```
let sportsTitle = renderedElement.props.children;
console.log("sportsTitle----->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTitle));
```

**JSON structure**
renderedElement----->

```
{
    "type": "div",
    "key": null,
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
        "className": "sports-page",
        "children": [
            {
                "type": "p",
                "key": "100",
                "ref": null,
                "props": {
                    "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": {
                        "__html": "hello world"
                    }
                },
                "_owner": null,
                "_store": {}
            }, 
            {
                "type": "p",
                "key": "200",
                "ref": null,
                "props": {
                    "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": {
                    "__html": "hello world2"
                }
            },
            "_owner": null,
            "_store": {}
        }]
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
}
```

Comment: You should format your code properly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try using a library like lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because renderedElement.props.children is an array, you need to know the index you want to touch like renderedElement.props.children[0].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html.

Comment: thanks for explaination..i didnt know array access...all this days...but the below code only worked enderedElement.props.children[0].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html;

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a crazy JSON structure, but try `renderedElement.key` and `renderedElement.props.children[props].dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html`